# Handling large json array on the browser to create tables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, datatable

I am currently working on an inventory management web app where I load a large amount of data on an HTML table by using fetch with async.

```js
async function getNewSummary() {
    try {
        let groups = await fetch(
            "http://localhost:3000/dashboard/summary/groups", {
                method: "GET"
            }
        );
        let groupData = await groups.json();
        console.log(json);
        var table = document.getElementById("grouptable");
        for (data in groupData)
            table.innerHTML = `<tr>
    <td>${groupData[data].groups}</td>
    <td>${groupData[data].permission}</td>
    </tr>`;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

My `Express` API returns a large JSON array which I loop through and create table rows from. I expected the browser to stop working when it does that. Is there any other way I can get it done?
I need to create the table and then use it as a `DataTable`.

Comment: You can try web worker.

Comment: Lazy loading with generators?

Comment: Datatable Data is faster then loop to create table rows. So, You can use directly datatable to load your JSON data. like [Datatable Data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/) and please review Renderers [Function](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers) to modify or customize your column, data and display format. Hope it helps.

Comment: So I tried to use web worker and datatable data object. First when I have an event to get data, I initiate a web worker, that generates a 2d array for data table then omits that array. Then I call a datatable maker where I destroy table and recreate with the new data. Its really good but it still makes the browser stop completely for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my current iteration.
inside the browser

```
<script>
function inventoryWorker() {
w = new Worker("js/tableHelper.js");
w.onmessage = function (event) {
DatatableMaker(event.data);
}
}


function DatatableMaker(data) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#main').DataTable().destroy();
var events = $("#events");
// Setup text input
$("#main tfoot th").each(function () {
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).html(
        '<input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title +
        '" />'
    );
});
// DataTable
var table = $("#main").DataTable({
    data: data,
    paging: true,
    lengthChange: true,
    searching: true,
    ordering: true,
    info: true,
    scrollX: true,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    autoWidth: true
});
}
</script>
```

In a seperate file `tableHelper.js`

```js
async function getInventory() {
    var tableRow = [];
    try {
        let inventory = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/dashboard/inventory", {
            method: "GET"
        });
        let inventoryData = await inventory.json();
        console.log(inventoryData);
        for (data in inventoryData) {
            var temp = [];
            temp.push(
                inventoryData[data].ReceivingDate,
// etc
            );
            tableRow.push(temp);
        }
        postMessage(tableRow);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

It works better but there is a slight pause when the `inventoryWorker` function is called

Answer (score 2):

Just curious, but I tried loading a pretty large dataset (28795 JSON objects) using your code as an example and it loaded pretty quickly. I adjusted the DOM manipulation to use something besides `innerHTML`, but other than that it is pretty much the same. Here is the request I made:

**main.js**

```
async function getNewSummary() {
    try {
        const groups = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prust/wikipedia-movie-data/master/movies.json");
        const groupData = await groups.json();
        console.log('Num documents: ', groupData.length);
        console.log('Example document: ', groupData[0]);
        const table = document.getElementById("grouptable");
        for (data in groupData) {
            let tr = document.createElement('tr');
            let td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = groupData[data].title;
            tr.appendChild(td);
            table.appendChild(tr);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}

getNewSummary();
```

And here is a gif of it working, it only takes about 2 seconds to create all 28,795 table rows. Could the problem be the way you are adding the data to the DOM and not the size of the dataset? Or is you dataset much larger? I've never worked with large amounts of data, so I could be wayyyy off base here, but wanted to try and help if I could.

[image]

Here is another version where I click a button that changes the background to red and adds some `p` tags while it's loading. It definitely hangs, but it's only for a second:

[image]

Comment: yes, in your case, not using innerhtml works great. But does the browser tab stop for a second?

Comment: @sakib11 I'm not sure I follow, what do you mean by 'browser tab stop'? There is about a 1-2 second delay, then all the data shows up, that gif isn't modified in any way. Is there something in the dev tools I should check for you on my end? I'm a novice developer, so this kind of thing isn't something I usually deal with.

Comment: No, sorry what I meant was when the page is loaded, are other elements in your browser tab functional? for me, when it is appending innerHTML, I can't click on anything else (for my ciode).

Comment: @sakib11 Ah, yes it definitely blocks my ability to add anything else to the dom. See my second gif. It's so quick I barely have time to notice. Maybe load the page first, then after everything is loaded make the fetch request?

Comment: thats what I currently do, I get everything loaded first. Then make fetch calls.

Comment: I was  under the impression that web worker would take care of doing something while not using up the main thread essentially leaving the user with clickable HTML stuff. Perhaps when I redraw the DataTable, it is still on the same main thread hence halting for a bit.